# socket.io not emitting to and from server and client

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, chat

I have made an app with nodejs and with socket.io which echos messages to and fro from the client to the server... Here's a tiny bit of my server code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
                    socket.on('sentmsg', function(msg){
                            io.emit('sentmsg', msg);
                    });
                });
```

And here's my code on the client side :

```
var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('sentmsg', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });
    socket.on('sentmsg', function(data){
        $('#boxf').append($('<li>').text(data));
        alert(data);

    });
```

It should append to the  element in my html code but it is changing into a url followed by a query string like `?msg="the msg I entered"`

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Though you are returning `false` from your `.submit()` handler which should stop the form post, I wonder if the form is still being submitted.

Comment: Could you update your post, how you are getting the instance of io? Also in client include where you have included the socket.io.js.  I suggest you to test your app first if form is successfully submitted and you are getting data in backend.